# Math about regression coefficient (OLS) when confounders are not included?

Tags: math, linear-regression

I am learning about maths for coefficients in linear regression, when there are unmeasured confounders.

> x1<-rnorm(10000,0,3)

> x2<-rnorm(10000,0,2)+1.2*x2

> x3<-rnorm(10000,0,1)+2*x1+3*x2

> 

> y<-0.5*x1+2*x2-1*x3

> lm(y~x3)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x3)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x3
0.02482     -0.45822

my question is why -0.45822!?   when there is no relationship between x1 and x2, then the coefficient is -0.54803, which I can calculate by hand. Could anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Just fyi, there are also https://math.stackexchange.com and https://stats.stackexchange.com